# Navigation bar and tags <ul> <li>

Tags: html, css

I still have a few difficulties concerning tags "ul" and "li"

In fact I would like to put my navigation bar in horizontal but it doesn't works.

I don't understand where is my problem ?

Look at the resultat
[image]

Here my blocks HTML

```
<div id="container_menu">
            <ul id="topnav2">
                <li class="active2"><href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">INVESTEMENT PLAN</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FAQS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">RULES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

And here is my CSS also

```
#container_menu {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right:65px;
  width: auto;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;

}

/* Le navigateur */ 

#topnav2 li {
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: 0px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13.333px;
  display: block;

}

/* Navbar links */

#topnav2 li a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  
}

#topnav2 li a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.active2 {
  background-color: #C52E1E;
  color: white;
}
```

Do you have an idea ?
Thank you a lot for an answer

Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with displaying inline <li> tags for horizontal nav bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51826939/issue-with-displaying-inline-li-tags-for-horizontal-nav-bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your float:left; from "**#topnav2 li a**" to "**#topnav2 li**". It should work.

```
/* Le navigateur */ 

#topnav2 li {
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    float: left;
    word-spacing: 0px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13.333px;
    display: block;

}

/* Navbar links */

#topnav2 li a {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may solve your problem if you use `inline-block` instead of `block` in `#topnav2 li`.

```
#topnav2 li {
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: 0px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13.333px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```